# Edit button in ionic doesnt work

Tags: ionic-framework

im trying to edit on selected item in modal view using the same item that are being added in the page.

**This is my index.html**

```
<button ion-button (click)="edit(item)">
          <ion-icon name="redo"></ion-icon>Edit
        </button>
```

**This is my index.ts

---

```
addItem(){

    let addModal = this.modalCtrl.create(AddItemPage);

    addModal.onDidDismiss((item) => {

          if(item){
            this.saveItem(item);
          }

    });

    addModal.present();

  }
edit(item){
  this.navCtrl.push(AddItemPage, {
    key: item.$key,
    listname: item.listname,
    today: item.today,
    description: item.description
  });
}
```

**This is my additem.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-additem',
  templateUrl: 'additem.html'
})
export class AddItemPage {

  listname: string;
  time: string;
  description: string;
  today: Date;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public view: ViewController) {

  }

  saveItem(){

    let newItem = {
      listname: this.listname,
      time: this.time,
      today: this.today,
      description: this.description,
      toogleIncomplete: this.toogleIncomplete,
      toogleComplete: this.toogleComplete,
    };

    this.view.dismiss(newItem);

  }

  close(){
    this.view.dismiss();
  }

}
```

**This is my additem.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="secondary">
    <ion-title>
      Add Item
    </ion-title>
      <ion-buttons end>
        <button ion-button icon-only (click)="close()"><ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon></button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>List Name</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="listname"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Time</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="time"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Description</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="description"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
     <ion-label>Incomplete</ion-label>
    <ion-toggle  ng-model="toogleIncomplete">
  </ion-toggle>
</ion-item>

 <ion-item>
     <ion-label>Complete</ion-label>
    <ion-toggle  ng-model="toogleComplete">
  </ion-toggle>
</ion-item>

  </ion-list>

  <button full ion-button color="secondary" (click)="saveItem()">Save</button>

</ion-content>
```

My Add item is success.. but edit button is not working and the toogle button also not working... HELP! :(

iam still confused what to do with my edit button. I did try to research on the issues, but still the edit button is not working

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd- I didnt have any error...it cannot be edited on the selected item in modal view with the existing one. :(

Comment: Can you show content of AddItemPage.ts and AddItemPage.html?

Comment: @SebastianStraburzyński- I just editted the page. :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a few things in your code:

AddItem() function should have a parameter and pass it to modal page:

```js
addItem(item){
    console.log('picked item: ', item);
    let addModal = this.modalCtrl.create(AddItemPage, {selectedItem: item});
    addModal.onDidDismiss((item) => {
        if(item) {
            console.log('returned item: ', item);
            // save item here
        }
    });
    addModal.present();
 }
}
```

AddItemPage should have injected NavParams in constructor to get passed parameters from previous page. I made also an object selectedItem and assign it to data (instead of separate fields).

```js
selectedItem: any;

constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public view: ViewController,
    public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.selectedItem = this.navParams.get('selectedItem');
}
```

And finally saveItem() function is passing selectedItem on dismiss, so home page can get this data.

```js
saveItem() {
    console.log('saved item: ', this.selectedItem);
    this.view.dismiss(this.selectedItem);
}
```

I made an working example here: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-uryz6d

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) You can mark this thread as solved. And good luck with your app.

Comment: edit button is working. however, when i want to add new item. it says...this -> TypeError: Cannot read property 'listname' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///AppModule/AddItemPage.ngfactory.js:284:43) - Why is that appears? is it because i entered the wrong code?

Comment: Yes, because I modified code to make edit button working with different model. You should consider make different page for creating items and editing existing item. I updated example on stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ajdudw

Comment: i still cant add a new item.. but i will try to recheck it again later..